# Creating variables in PowerShell scripts using New-Variable vs using assignment operator "="

Tags: powershell

What is the difference between using New-Variable and using the assignment operator "=" to create variables in PowerShell scripts?

e.g.

```coffee
$var1 = "lalalala"
```

vs

```coffee
New-Variable var1 "lalalala"
```

Comment: [The cmdlet creates a new variable in Windows PowerShell. You can assign a value to the variable while creating it or assign or change the value after it is created.

You can use the parameters of New-Variable to set the properties of the variable, set the scope of a variable, and determine whether variables are public or private.

Typically, you create a new variable by typing the variable name and its value, such as $Var = 3, but you can use the New-Variable cmdlet to use its parameters.](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-variable#description)

Comment: In other words, I would like to advise (any StackOverflow/PowerShell newbie) to read the (online) help related to the [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview) in the question, e.g.: [`Get-Help New-Variable -Online`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New-Variable have additional parameters like `description`, `constant` which can be useful in some cases.